# Mongoose create conflict after one document saved to database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I can't for the life of me figure out what simple thing I'm doing wrong here. I've widdled the user schema down to one property, name. When i post the first one to the database all is well and it is saved. When I try to save another one with a different name I get CONFLICT. It must be something super simple I'm missing but I need an extra set of eyes to check it out.

Here's my schema (**user.js**)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  }
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = userSchema;
```

Here's my my post request (**index.js**)

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

// db connection and models
var conn = require('./db');
var User = conn.model('User');

// middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
```

// POST - create a user

```
app.post('/api/user', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  User.create(req.body, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      if (err.code === 11000) {
        return res.sendStatus(409); // conflict
      } else {
        return res.sendStatus(500); // server error
      }
    }
    res.sendStatus(200); // ok - user created
  });  
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening...');
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: For some reason - I can add one document to the MongoLab db I have set up. But when I try and post another document the 409 conflict status is sent.

Answer (score 2):

Model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/webservice', function(err){
if(err){
  throw err; 
}else{
  console.log('Connect');
}
});
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
email: String,
city: String,
age: String
});
var User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var User = require('./model');

app.post('/User',function(req, res){
    var Newuser = req.body.user;

    User.create(Newuser, function(err, user){
        res
        .status(201)
        .json({
            user : user
        });

    })
})
```

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
/**
*   Variables
*/
var  server= module.exports = express();

/**
*   Middleware
*/
server.use(bodyParser.json('aplication/json'))

/** 
*   Routes
*/

 var users = require('./lib/users');
 server.use(users);


 if(!module.parent){
  server.listen(4000, function(){
  console.log("listen 4000 en http://localhost:4000")
  });

  } else {
   module.exports = server;
  }
```

Structure

```
/Project
 /lib
    /users
          -index.js
          -model.js
 server.jse
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this together - but do you see what's wrong with my code?

Comment: When you create his Schema                                                                         var userSchema = new Schema({
  /*name: {
    type: String
  }*/ name: String
});

Comment: Sorry - could you be more specific?

Comment: When you create his Schema his sintax i think that is incorrect        userSchema = new Schema({ name: { type: String }}) Or you can explain why? use into name the Type of data????

Comment: I wonder why it would save the first time though but not the second?